# How to delete managed disk snapshot every 10 minutes

Tags: azure, powershell

I have the below script which I am using in order to delete snapshot older then 10 minutes and retain the snapshot that are not older then 10minutes, I have the below script but its not working as it suppose to, can anyone tell me whats being going wrong?

```
foreach($snapname in $snapshotnames)
{
    Get-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $rg  -SnapshotName $snapname |?{$_.Name -Like "*-Server1*"} | ?{($_.TimeCreated).ToString('yyyyMMdd') -lt ([datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-10).tostring('yyyymmdd'))} | remove-azurermsnapshot -force
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `[datetime]::UtcNow` instead of `[datetime]::Now` and not use `.tostring('yyyymmdd')`.

So your command should be:

```
foreach($snapname in $snapshotnames)
{
    Get-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $rg -SnapshotName $snapname | ?{$_.Name -Like "*-Server1*"} | ?{($_.TimeCreated) -lt ([datetime]::UtcNow.AddMinutes(-10))} | remove-azurermsnapshot -force
}
```

My specific test command:

```
Get-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>" -SnapshotName "<SnapshotName>" | ?{($_.TimeCreated) -lt ([datetime]::UtcNow.AddMinutes(-10))} | remove-azurermsnapshot -force
```

Result screenshot:

[image]

Comment: does the .tostring wont matter here? Or dow we suppose to add that?

Comment: @testuser1 I have not test it, even if it doesn't matter,also I think it is unnecessary to use it, because we are comparing with minute.

Comment: Okay, what about if I want to delete snapshots older then 14 days?

Comment: I just want to automate this, using the automation account, so making sure that nothing goes wrong. Does time zones matter, my server is in East Asia.

Comment: @testuser1  1. Try `UtcNow.AddDays(-14)`. 2. No, the command uses utc time, no matter what the server will been.