# Delete Azure Snapshots older than X days

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

I am close to what I need but I am missing something because the snapshot isn't removing. I think its the datetime string I have isn't all the way correct, so I am here for a little help. Here is my current PS code.

```
rg = 'snapshots'
$snapshotnames = (Get-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $rg).name

foreach($snapname in $snapshotnames)
{
    Get-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $rg  -SnapshotName $snapname |
        ?{($_.TimeCreated).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd') -lt ([datetime]::Today.AddDays(-1).tostring('yyyy-MM-dd'))} |
        remove-azurermsnapshot -force
}
```

The name of the snapshot is formatted like this with the below code: Testvm---2018-09-20

```
$timestamp = Get-Date -f ---yyyy-MM-dd
$snapshotName = $vmInfo.Name + $timestamp
```

So I think my problem area is this part

```
?{($_.TimeCreated).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd') -lt ([datetime]::Today.AddDays(-1).tostring('yyyy-MM-dd'))} | remove-azurermsnapshot -force
```

Comment: You're trying to compare two string values using `-lt`, this isn't going to work in the way you want. Try removing `.ToString()` and you might get a better result comparing the native `datetime` objects instead :)

Comment: like this: `?{($_.TimeCreated) -lt ([datetime]::Today.AddDays(-1))} | remove-azurermsnapshot -force`

Comment: I ran this and nothing was deleted. There is one vm in the said resource group that was created today (9/20/2018) `$rg = 'snapshots'
$snapshotnames = (Get-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $rg).name

foreach($snapname in $snapshotnames)
{
    Get-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $rg  -SnapshotName $snapname |?{($_.TimeCreated) -lt ([datetime]::Today.AddDays(-1))} | remove-azurermsnapshot -force | remove-azurermsnapshot -force

}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the command below, the sample delete snapshots older then `10` days.

```
rg = 'snapshots'
$snapshotnames = (Get-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $rg).name

foreach($snapname in $snapshotnames)
{
    Get-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $rg -SnapshotName $snapname | ?{($_.TimeCreated) -lt ([datetime]::UtcNow.AddDays(-10))} | remove-azurermsnapshot -force
}
```

**My specify test command**:

```
Get-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName joywebapp -SnapshotName joytestss1 | ?{($_.TimeCreated) -lt ([datetime]::UtcNow.AddDays(-10))} | remove-azurermsnapshot -force
```

[image]

**My snapshot**:

[image]

**Also check the logs in the portal**:

[image]

Here is a similar issue, refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51826374/how-to-delete-managed-disk-snapshot-every-10-minutes/51833853#51833853).

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. I took off the .tostring and formating the time portion off. `Get-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $rg  -SnapshotName $snapname | ?{($_.TimeCreated) -lt ([datetime]::Now.AddDays(0))} #| remove-azurermsnapshot -force` this was my code section that works, thank you and thanks to @James C for your help.